# In JetEngine Forms, where are the submissions / entries stored?

Tags: wordpress, forms, submission

In WordPress [JetEngine](https://crocoblock.com/plugins/jetengine/) Forms you can create forms. When a user submits it, where does the data go? In GravityForms, you can edit a form and [see a list of all submissions so far](https://docs.gravityforms.com/reviewing-form-submissions/). Does JetEngine honestly lack that? Can't find it in the docs; can't find them in the DB either.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can auto-create a post of the (JetEngine) custom post type (i.e.) "form submission".

First set up the custom post type. Make sure to exclude it from the search. You can set it to private too, but then it doesn't appear in the forms dropdown anymore where we're gonna need it. (You can make the CPT public first, then set up the action, and make the CPT private afterwards. The association in the action's dropdown still stands, albeit now the dropdown value is empty … Seems a bit buggy and dangerous to do it that way)

Create a Meta Field for each form field.

Then edit the form and, next to "Send mail" or whatever your primary submit action is, add another action which is to "Insert/Update Post". Choose the CPT and map the form fields to the meta fields.

It's a bit cumbersome because of this redundant field management … But it's doable.